# PHP explode return different results

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a string from front end application json. Need to call explode(' ', $string) on it and make some logic above the result. The string looks like "27 609,66 CZK". But it seems like there are not spaces in the string and explode return whole string as is. I also tried to use non beaking space sign as separator. But no success. I made simple test on it which looks like:

```
$a = explode(" ", "27 609,66 CZK");  // This is the application string
$b = explode(" ", "27 609,66 CZK");  // This is written on keyboard

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

The result looks like

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '27 609,66 CZK' (length=15)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '27' (length=2)
  1 => string '609,66' (length=6)
  2 => string 'CZK' (length=3)
```

Can somebody tell me plaese what could be the problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. https://3v4l.org/JtGVH

Comment: Regular space is [U+0020](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0020), but there're many characters that can render as a blank. You can use [bin2hex()](https://php.net/bin2hex) or paste to https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect to verify what your input is. (If you have one of those chars, they didn't survive being pasted in Stack Overflow).

Comment: You already defined the problem yourself: "there are not spaces in the string". So you have to investigate what these characters are and where did they come from

Comment: _"I also tried to use non beaking space sign as separator. But no success."_ - and _how_ exactly did you try that? Just telling us _that_ you something tried isn't particularly helpful, we can't tell if you might have simply done it _wrong_ somehow ...

Comment: Your var_dump there said `length=15`, so it looks like each of those spaces is actually two bytes. And since the value appears to be monetary value, it is probably also highly likely, that non-breaking spaces where used - because people usually don't want such a price display to break into multiple lines. A non-breaking space character in UTF-8 is `C2 A0` (hex), so `explode("\xC2\xA0", "...")` should do the job.

Comment: Could use `preg_split` and then you don't need to know which space characters are being used. `$a = preg_split("/\h+/", "27 609,66 CZK");`

Comment: @CBroe This is the case and it works. But I am not sure I can relied that front end always send me this characters. May be some browser will send something else....

Comment: Then use preg_split instead, and split the data at _any_ whitespace character.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I will use preg_split instead. Ok thank you.